# Reduce time of api that calls google distance matrix api 1000 times

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a node.js express api that gets lat-long coordinates of the user in request body. It then calculates distances between 1000 people's coordinates by calling the google api endpoint 1000 times by calculating distance between each coordinate with user's coordinate.

What things can be done to minimize the time taken in doing so by this api written in node.js backend server.